# Excel formula that does both right and replace in one cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of URLs in a column like below:

```
https://www.example.com/xx/yy/product-name-could-be-30238543/
https://www.example.com/xx/yy/product-name-might-70293274/
https://www.example.com/xx/yy/product-name-may-40242653/
```

I wish to extract the ID's from the id but not with the last / in them. The right function gives me below:

40242653/ but i wish to get rid of the ID's too within the same function so can someone suggest a way?

Otherwise, i have to use another replace function separately to get rid of ending trailing slashes.

Thanks,

Comment: Use `MID` perhaps.

Comment: or wrap the Right in SUBSTITUTE

Comment: ^^^^^ This is definitely the simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

If all the IDs have 8 numerals, then you can use:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,9),8)
```

If they have more or less than 8 numerals, then ignore this answer.

Comment: so easy to write!! you made my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be easier to use (It extracts everything after the last occurrence of - in them.

```
SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("@";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"-";"@";(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"-";"")))/LEN("\"))));"/";"";1)
```